# Query function in MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have to create a query function in MS Access VBA, so that I can easily call a query when I click on a command button. My function looks like this:

```vb
Public Function fCreateQueries(ByVal strQueryToRun As String) As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim qryRun As QueryDef
    'My sql statement

    strSQL1 = "SELECT gender, TannerSum, Jahr FROM Tabelle1 WHERE gender = '1'"

    With CurrentDb
        Set qryRun = .CreateQueryDef(strQueryToRun, strSQL1)
        DoCmd.OpenQuery qryRun.Name
        .QueryDefs.Delete qryRun.Name
    End With

    Set qryRun = Nothing        

End Function
```

I have tried calling the function, but it won't run.

Comment: Why open a query and then in next line delete it? And why routinely create/delete? Your SQL is not dynamic to suggest not saving as a stored query.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function, what "won't run", the function or the query?

If the query, I do these type queries like this:

```
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL1
```

remove all the "with CurrentDB" and use these two lines.